# Django, как реализовать регистрацию разными методами

Tags: python, django

Подскажите как реализовать в Django 1.11 так, чтобы одни пользователи при входе авторизировались по телефону, а остальные по email, и все с разными правами доступа?

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, phone, password=None):
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError('Please, enter the correct phone number')

        user = self.model(phone=phone)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone, password):
        user = self.create_user(phone=phone, password=password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


    class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number   must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
        phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], blank=True, max_length=15)
        phone = models.IntegerField(('contact number'), unique=True, db_index=True)
        # email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
        is_admin = models.BooleanField('superuser', default=False)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone'

    def get_full_name(self):
        return str(self.phone)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return str(self.phone)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.phone)
```

Comment: Спасибо, исправил

Comment: вопрос слишком общий, не очень понятно какую роль тут играют разные права доступа.